# Problems with template <typename ...Args>

Tags: c++, templates

I try to make a function that will run a for loop on multiple threads. 
To make the function better to use with all sorts of functions that should be used in the for loop I decided to use templates. 
For the return type of each function I used a simple:

```
template <typename T>
```

That is working without any problems. But for the arguments that the function may need I use this template construction:

```
template <typename ...Args>
```

So now my code looks something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
T threadedFor(T func(Args... args), Args... args, int nThreads, unsigned int max, unsigned int min = 0) {
    T result;
    /* ... */
    return result;
}
```

The problem now is that I don't know how to pass in the `Args... args` in my function call.
I tried several methods, like:

```
threadedFor(function(1), 4, 5, 0);
```

or this:

```
threadedFor(function, 1, 4, 5, 0);
```

Assuming my arguments here are 1.

Also it would be nice to know what the name of this construction `typename ...Args` is, since I couldn't find something on google...

Comment: With your attempts, do you get build errors? What errors? What do they tell you?

Comment: `typename ...Args` declares a parameter pack for a variadic template.

Comment: And the term you're looking for is [*parameter packs*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude build errors with what? With my function declaration there are no errors. With my function call, I get `No matching function for call to 'threadedFor'`.

Comment: That "No matching function..." is a build error. When you ask questions with code that results in build errors (the compiler or linker complaining) then you should always include the full and complete output into the question. Sometimes there might be hints about the problems in the compiler messages that we could point out for you.

Comment: What is `function`? Present your [mcve].

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica as you probably should have guessed by the name `function` this is just an example function. Also this is irrelevant to the question, since the problem isn't with that function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are absolutely right, but because the error only is that one I posted, it isn't very useful and also I can interpret that on my own, I didn't include it.

Comment: @user11914177 How do you know the problem isn't with that function?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica because the problem is passing in the function parameters...

Comment: You know that now. You didn't when you wrote the question, and neither did anyone reading it! You must present a [mcve] in your questions so that we are not left to guess at the details. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to help you to produce quality questions that will help you to get quality answers. From us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to "NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica" I found the name of this construct and also found a solution to my problem. A parameter package must always be the last argument of a function. So changing my function like this:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
T threadedFor(T func(Args... args), int nThreads, unsigned int min, unsigned int max, Args... args) {
```

solves the problem.

Comment: _"A parameter package must always be the last argument of a function."_ [This isn't really true](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02567cf5fecae714), though it matters if you're not specifying the argument types explicitly.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Thanks